# Detect if the phone rotated 360 degrees in Android

Tags: android, rotation, sensors, android-sensors

I need to find a way to detect if the phone has rotated 360 degrees, by using (preferably) the accelerometer, gyroscope and/or compass. But there is another catch: When the phone is in portrait mode, I need to detect the rotation along the Y axis, and when in landscape mode the rotation along the X axis. But what if the phone is in between those two modes?

Is this possible to achieve and if so, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It's a game of maths - suppose each Vector3 of current angles has its exact list of vectors containing the next rotations angles. You could compare your given angles captured with the accelerometer and see if you find a match. Another way will be to find a formula that does that - I'm sure there are online, but I have know idea WHAT do you even search when you need such a thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420999/how-to-detect-one-full-turn-360-degrees-of-the-phone